# Where can I download the specified version of spring source code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, springsource

I think if I really want to the understand how does the spring or spring MVC work. Such as why and how the HTTP request can reach the controller in the spring MVC. I think the best way to achieve that is debugging the source code in the IDE.

So Where can I download the source code? So can attach the source code to the dependence library in IDE. Let's say the version 4.2.4. Thanks.

Comment: In Eclipse and Intellij, you can choose to download the Javadoc and the sources with the maven plugin. It will be easier for you to debug

Comment: Can be done in the MyEclipse? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from github -

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v4.2.4.RELEASE